# Возвратить значения CSS свойств $(object).css("margin")

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо возвратить некоторые из CSS свойств элемента HTML-страницы в понятном виде для Edge, IE.
Конкретно: необходимо вернуть значения отступов и полей элемента и применить их для анимации других элементов.
`this !== object`

```
$(this).animate({
    width: "toggle",
    margin: $(object).css("margin"),
    padding: ($(object).css("padding"))
}, time, "linear");
```

Данная конструкция работает в Chrome, но совершенно бесполезна в Edge и IE.
Если указать значения руками вида "2px 10px", отрабатывают все.
Возможно ли сделать иначе ?

---

---

**РЕШЕНИЕ**: *для IE и Edge стоит забирать значения для каждой стороны отдельно и потом конактенировать в нужную строку-параметр.*

---

---

UPD1: Почитал API, получается, что $(object).css(propertyName) возвращает строку вида `значение` (без кавычек). Из этого выходит, что Edge и IE не понимают.
Добавил кавычки на концах, т.е. "\"" + $(object).css(propertyName) + "\""
После этого получается строка вида `"значение"`. В таком виде все три браузера стали понимать одинаково, но ни один из них корректно не отрабатывает, а именно не растягивает те поля и отступы, которые уменьшались с помощью анимации перед растягиванием анимацией.

UPD2:
Последовательность действий:
1. Нажать два раза по "ddd"
2. Нажать два раза по любому другому элементу.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
       var time = 200;
       var delay = time + 100;

       $(".icon-language").click(function() {
         slide($(".rightBlockMenu i"), $(this), time);
         $(".hidden").delay(delay).animate({
           width: "show"
         }, time, "linear");
       });
       
       $(".icon-search-1").click(function () {
        slide($(".rightBlockMenu i"), $(this), time);
      });

    $(".icon-user-o").click(function () {
        slide($(".rightBlockMenu i"), $(this), time);
    });

    $(".icon-basket").click(function () {
        slide($(".rightBlockMenu i"), $(this), time);
    });
})

function slide(selector, object, time) {
       if (selector.not(object).css("display") != "none") {
         selector.not(object).animate({
           width: "hide",
           margin: "0px -1px",
           padding: "9px 0px"
         }, time, "linear");
         $(object).animate({
           margin: "0"
         }, time).addClass("active_i");
       }
       if (selector.not(object).css("display") == "none") {
         selector.each(function (){
           if ($(this).is(selector.last())) {
             $(this).animate({
               width: "show",
               margin: "0 0 0 6px",
               padding: "\"" + $(object).css("padding") + "\""
             }, time, "linear");
             $(this).removeClass("active_i");
           } else {
             $(this).animate({
               width: "show",
               margin: "0 6px",
               padding: "9px 18px"
             }, time, "linear", function() {
               if ($(this).is(selector.first())) {
                 $(this).css("margin-left", "0");
               }
             });
             $(this).removeClass("active_i");
           }
         });
     }
     }
```

```css
.header_top {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.rightBlock {
  max-height: 100%;
  padding-right: 10px;
  float: right;
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.rightBlockMenu {
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 80%, 1);
  font-size: 2.7em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.rightBlockMenu i:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.rightBlockMenu i:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.rightBlockMenu i:hover {
  color: hsla(0, 70%, 45%, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rightBlockMenu i {
  padding: 9px 18px;
  margin: 0 6px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 80%, 1);
  display: inline-block;
}

.active_i {
  color: hsla(0, 70%, 45%, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header_top">
  <div class="rightBlock">
    
    <div class="rightBlockMenu">
      <i class="icon-language">aaa</i>
      <i class="icon-search-1" >bbb</i>
      <i class="icon-user-o" >ccc</i>
      <i class="icon-basket" >ddd</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Непонял, в IE не работает `$(object).css("margin")` и `$(object).css("padding")` ?

Comment: у меня не работает. элементы появляются, а свойства margin и padding им не присваиваются

Comment: Может дело в селекторе `object`? Вы уверены, что он ведёт к правильному элементу?

Comment: а почему у вас в одном случае без скобок, а во втором со скобками: `padding: ($(object).css("padding"))`?

Comment: а когда речь идёт об IE, всегда пишите версию, потому что IE это один большой баг и в зависимости от глубины версии может не работать что угодно

Comment: На скобочки не обращайте внимания. IE 11. Edge 38.14393.0.0. В селекторе object уверен.

Comment: сделай сниппет с [mcve] чтобы наконец можно было запустить и увидеть проблему

Answer (score 0):

Для начала приведи все className к единому виду.
.rightBlockMenu
.header_top
.icon-search-1

Че за фигня? где единое правило написания стилей.

лучше свойства применяй не на прямую, а пиши классы, а потом подключай и отключай их, если свойств больше одного:
elem.classList.add();
elem.classList.remove();
elem.classList.toggle();
если одно css свойство - на усмотрение.

У тебя сильно много текста, но исходя из титульного вопроса, чтоб сбросить css свойство - нужно ему применить "". И оно тогда станет по либо то что просписано у тебя в внешних стилях, либо по умолчанию (свойство браузера). в общем ghjcnj удалиться из атрибута style="";

Answer (score 0):

window.getComputedStyle(object)['margin'] даст вам все значения margin в виде строки во всех браузерах как и в IE9+ и Edge